# How to remove repeating letter in a dataframe?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, countvectorizer

I have the following string:

```
"hello, I'm going to eat to the fullest today hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"
```

I have collected many tweets like that and assigned them to a dataframe. How can I clean those rows in dataframe by removing "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" and only let the rest of the string in that row?

I'm also using countVectorizer later, so there was a lot of vocabularies that contained 'hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh'

Comment: Can you show a few more samples of the data in the df. Also, do you just want to remove repeated h or any repeated letter in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(u"h{4,}", "")
```

Where you may set the number of characters to match in my case 4.

```
                                        Col
0  hello, I'm today hh hhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
1                               Hello World
                     Col
0  hello, I'm today hh  
1            Hello World
```

I used unicode matching, since you mentioned you are in tweets.

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ["hello, I'm going to eat to the fullest today hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh", "Hello World"]})
#df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(r"\b(.)\1+\b", "")
df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(r"\s+(.)\1+\b", "").str.strip()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                             Col
0  hello, I'm going to eat to the fullest today 
1                                    Hello World
```

Comment: Won't this remove `"'ll"` from `"He'll eat  to the fullest today"`, too?

Comment: Maybe use `\b(.)\4+\b`

Comment: `df["Col"] = df["Col"].str.replace(r"\s+(.)\1+\b", "").str.strip()` ?